# PyQt Get the result from a popup window

Tags: windows, popup, pyqt

I want to open a popup window in pyqt interface using this class

```
class MyPopup(QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    QWidget.__init__(self)
    self.initUI()
    self.res=0

  def initUI(self):
        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Continue', self)
        self.btn.move(20, 160)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.showDialogcontinue)
        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit', self)
        self.btn.move(180,160)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.showDialogstop)
        self.setGeometry(600, 600, 290, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('EUT Setup')
        self.show()

  def showDialogcontinue(self):
    self.close()
    self.res=1

  def showDialogstop(self):
    self.close()
    self.res=0
```

So when I use it, in a  push button method

```
    self.w = MyPopup()
    self.w.setGeometry(QRect(100, 100, 400, 200))
    self.w.show()
    if self.w.res==1:
        print "start"
        self.__thread.start()
    else:
        print "stop"
```

I can't get the result to launch or not mythread ___thread .
Please what's wrong? Could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that showing a widget does not block the execution of code. So the `if` check is reached long before any button in the widget is clicked.

To solve this you can change the parent class to a [QDialog](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdialog.html), and show it with `exec_()` which will block until the dialog is closed.

And setting `self.res=0` before `self.initUI()` since anything after `self.initUI()` would be called after the dialog closed. And that would reset `res` to 0 again.

```
class MyPopup(QtGui.QDialog):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(MyPopup, self).__init__(parent)
    self.res=0
    self.initUI()

  def initUI(self):
        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Continue', self)
        self.btn.move(20, 160)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.showDialogcontinue)
        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit', self)
        self.btn.move(180,160)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.showDialogstop)
        self.setGeometry(600, 600, 290, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('EUT Setup')
        self.exec_()

  def showDialogcontinue(self):
    self.res=1
    self.close()

  def showDialogstop(self):
    self.res=0
    self.close()
```

if all you need is a single true\false value back from the dialog. You can do it easier using the accept\reject functions of a QDialog.

```
class MyPopup(QtGui.QDialog):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyPopup, self).__init__()
    self.initUI()

  def initUI(self):
        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Continue', self)
        self.btn.move(20, 160)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.accept)
        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit', self)
        self.btn.move(180,160)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.reject)
        self.setGeometry(600, 600, 290, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('EUT Setup')

w = MyPopup()
if w.exec_():
    print("Start thread")
else:
    print("Stop")
```